# Speeding up udisks2.service in linux

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, udisks

I'm analyzing the systemd and I want to improve my system's booting speed.The number one service in the blame list of `systemd-analyze` by a clear gap is `udisks2.service` with almost 10 seconds ( those numbers might be misleading because of the dependencies but `udisks` doesn't have any ) . It's not a good solution to disable it since it's needed by another service :

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/udisks2.service
...
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I also tried disabling it in a test instance of ubuntu in VirtualBox , it booted completely and without problem but once the `dbus-daemon` got initialized , it automatically started it.

From `man udisksd` :

> Users or administrators should never need to start
> this daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) or
> systemd(1) whenever an application tries to access its D-Bus
> interfaces

In the `udisks2.conf` manpage it is stated that you can set the `modules_load_preference` option to `ondemand` and by default it is. It seems that currently it's in the most optimum form.
So the question is "Is it possible to safely speedup the execution of /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a block device/partition/LV that is *not* listed in `/etc/fstab` (and so looks like a candidate for `udisksd` management) but is encrypted or otherwise not easily identifiable?

Or maybe a CD drive or a memory card reader with a slow or non-existent detection of a "no media in drive" error? In the case of a memory card reader, a symptom of this situation might be I/O timeout errors for that device in `dmesg` output.

In these cases, you might want to exclude these problem devices from `udisksd` management, by creating an `udev` rule matching the problem device and adding the `ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"` attribute to it.

The rule could be as simple as

```
KERNEL=="sda6", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"   # encrypted disk
```

or by device serial number

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="S467NX0KB24459Y", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

or by any valid combination of `udev` attributes.

You might want to read `[/usr]/lib/udev/rules.d/*-udisks2.rules` for examples and informative comments, but you should add your own rules to `/etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules` so it won't be overwritten by system updates. `udev` will read both directories, and if there is a file with the exact same name in both, the file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` will override the corresponding system file. In this case, you probably won't need to override the system default rules files; just add your own rule file with a non-overlapping name.

You can use any filename as long as it is in the correct directory and has the `.rules` suffix, but remember that the rules are executed in the default US-ASCII sorting order of the filenames, so there is a convention to add a number prefix to the filename to make the rule ordering explicit.

Comment: "Do you have a block device/partition/LV that is not listed in /etc/fstab?" : **Yes** . "but is encrypted or otherwise not easily identifiable?" : **No**. It doesn't happen most often however that was a nice guide.I didn't know the env variable ```UDISKS_IGNORE```.Thanks :)